# Livewire User Gallery and Spabie Media Library Pro

Tags: laravel

I am wanting to create a user image gallery, where the user can upload an image to either a public or private image gallery using Livewire 3, Laravel 10 and Spabie Media Library Pro

I have the following code but cannot get it to work, I keep getting errors. Have I missed anything obvious or have I gone about it the wrong way?

The Gallery Model

```
namespace App\Models;

use App\Models\User;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\HasMedia;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\InteractsWithMedia;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;

class Gallery extends Model implements HasMedia
{
    use HasFactory, InteractsWithMedia;

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function registerMediaCollections(): void
    {
        $this->addMediaCollection('public-images')
              ->maxFiles(10);  
    
        $this->addMediaCollection('private-images') 
              ->maxFiles(10); 
    }
}
```

The Livewire Component

```
<?php

namespace App\Livewire\Users;

use Livewire\Component;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Spatie\MediaLibraryPro\Livewire\Concerns\WithMedia;

class Gallery extends Component
{
    use WithMedia;

    public $galleryphotos = [];
    public $selectedCollection = 'public-images';

    protected $rules = [
        'galleryphotos.*' => 'image|max:1024', // Image, max 1MB
        'galleryphotos' => 'max:10' // Max 10 images
    ];

    public function updatedGalleryphotos()
    {
        $this->validate();
    }

    public function uploadGallery()
    {
        $user = Auth::user();

        $user->addFromMediaLibraryRequest($this->galleryphotos )
            ->each(function ($file) {
                $file->toMediaCollection($this->selectedCollection);
            });

        $this->reset('galleryphotos');
    }
```

The Blade

```
<div>
    <form wire:submit.prevent="uploadGallery" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    <label for="collection">Upload To:</label>
    <select id="collection" wire:model="selectedCollection">
        <option value="public-images">Public Gallery</option>
        <option value="private-images">Private Gallery</option>
    </select>

    <livewire:media-library wire:model="galleryphotos" rules="mimetypes:image/png,image/jpeg" />

    <x-button type="submit">Submit</x-button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: What errors do you get?